# Visual Studio Node NPM sequelize / tedious dependencies (not listed in package.json)

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js, tedious

I am trying to install sequelize and then tedious. I run *npm install sequelize*, for example. After installing, the Solution Explorer lists a copious number of packages that are suffixed by *(not listed in package.json)*. I have never seen this before and don't know if this is a corrupt install, or whether it is okay. It doesn't look pretty. I have tried an *npm ci* and *npm update* and neither fixed the issue. Should I care? Or just collapse that folder and keep going?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's a normal, after install any lib.
what happens is that the sequelize module has its own dependencies, so it will also install them. Remember that every time a lib is installed, it will certainly install other libs and in the end, we will have n folders.

for example:

```
npm i express
```

several folders with express dependencies will be created

[express dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yow5p.png)

Comment: Is there a way to hide all those dependencies in the Solution Explorer in VS? Strange that I only saw core package names that were in package.json until I installed sequelize and tedious. Now I cleaned everything, installed express only and it shows many dependencies. These hadn't appeared before.

Comment: no, just leave it minimized. These files are required.